# $f$ continuous iff $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ is embedding

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map and let $X\times Y$ be the product space.

Now I have to show that $f$ is continuous iff $x\mapsto (x,f(x))\subset X\times Y$ is an embedding.

I have already proved the direction $"\Rightarrow"$, but now I have trouble showing the other way. I have tried to use that $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ is 
continuous and injective, but I just won't see how to proceed.

Any help or adive is appreciated!

Comment: If $G$ is the graph of $f,$ then $z \mapsto p_1z$ is a bijection of $G$ onto $X;$ and by the hypotheses, an isomorphism.

Comment: Could I just write $f=p_Y\circ\Gamma_f$? And then $f$ is obivously continuous. (for $\Gamma_f :x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\mapsto f(x)$ is the composition of the two continuous functions $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ and $\pi_2:X\times Y\to Y$. Being the composition of two continuous functions, it must be continuous.